# I want to create more threads to calculate the sum of a user given input

Tags: c, pthreads

I have this program that asks for user input to give a number to calculate the sum of 1 to n (n being the user input number), using threads. I am trying to figure out how I could make a second thread calculate 1 to n+1, a third thread to calculate 1 to n+2 and so on.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <pthread.h>

void * thread_sum(void *);
int TotalSum=0;
pthread_mutex_t mVar=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{
    int iNumber,iCount;
    pthread_t tid, tid2;
    printf("Enter Number Up to Which You want to Sum :");
    scanf("%d",&iNumber);    
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_sum,(void *)&iNumber);
    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread_sum,(void *)&iNumber);
    for(iCount=1;iCount<=iNumber;iCount=iCount+2)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mVar);
        TotalSum=TotalSum + iCount;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mVar);
    }

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);

    printf("Thread %d running, Final Sum is : %d \n", tid,TotalSum);

}
void *thread_sum(void *no)
{
    int *iNumber,iCount, res;
    iNumber=(int*)no;

    for(iCount=2;iCount<=*iNumber;iCount=iCount+2)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mVar);
        TotalSum=TotalSum + iCount;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mVar);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);    
}
```

Comment: You do realize that the sum of `[1..n]` is `((n+1)*n)/2`

Comment: Is this intended as a serious usage of threads, or a "toy" example?

Comment: @duskwuff a toy example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling thread_sum with the address of iNumber, you can send the number of elements you want to calculate.

```
pthread_create(&tid,NULL,thread_sum,(void *)(iNumber+1));
pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,thread_sum,(void *)(iNumber+2));
```

and then use it in thread_sum:

```
void *thread_sum(void *no)
{
    int *iNumber,iCount, res;
    iNumber=(int)no;

    for(iCount=2;iCount<=iNumber;iCount=iCount+2)
```

Hope I helped

Comment: Edited and removed the * from iNumber (in the for loop) as it is now used as integer and not as pointer. Try now.